# compiler option for setting Default calling convention?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, calling-convention

I kind of recall that in Turbo Pascal or early Delphi versions there were options to make functions calling convention not register by default but any other type.

Maybe i mistake it for {$W+} or {$STACKFRAMES ON} option, which affects functions prologue and epilogue as well.

I do not want to use pascal pre-processors, but if i could change default convention for some unit it could be useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done. The default calling convention cannot be modified by compiler options.

Comment: Pity :-(
I'd not like to pollute both IDE MSBuild and command-line build script with preprocessors dependencies

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you want a different calling convention?

Comment: Porting really old modular project from D2006/DLL to XE2/BPL. Development is in process and keeping support for few earlier released DLL-based versions is needed. And while i can have stdcall in BPLs, i'd rather have avoided that. Though it is not big issue, it just keeps me feeling itchy.

Answer (score 2):

Free Pascal has the $calling directive:

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu7.html#x13-120001.1.7

It's typically used to fix old units that have assembler routines with assumptions
about calling convention built in to them.

Comment: it is local directive, isn't it ? it affects functions declared after it and before EOF or next such directive ?

Comment: Yes, like most non linking and non $Mode ones. Be careful though, $mode (specially {$mode delphi} might reset it.